# How to setup the Facebook web SDK securely

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have been making web applications for around 4 years now, and I have always had troubles setting up the Facebook web SDK.

But for my new application I really wanted to make the Facebook integration.

The problem I am facing now, is that I am using the JS SDK witch was fairly easy to set up, but now I want to build my backend to support it all. The flow I came up with was like this:

1. The user logs in
2. The user giving me their FB-id
3. A call from the back end create the new profile or logs if its a older user
4. The api gives back a api key for the other requestes.

The problem I see with this flow is, that if another person haves another users facebook id, they can obtain a api key for that user, just by sending the request with that id to the server.

How can I make this secure. I don't really thing that the docs on facebook are great, and the other tutorials on the web dos not cover this topic.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: The user logs in and you get an access token. Pass the access token to the backend. There is no way anyone can get someone else access token without hacking them.

Comment: So thanks @WizKid - i just thing It would be great if someone could show, the complete aspect of setting up a facebook login flow

Comment: I don't think anyone would stop you if you wrote a guide how to do it.